# Regex need to have two conditional end conditions

Tags: python, regex

I need to have a regex that deals with different end conditions, my idea was something like this, but it does not work

```
re.findall(r'(?<=tests\[")(.*)((?="\])|(?=:)', input_string])
```

inputs are in this format:

```
tests["Status code: " +responseCode.code] = responseCode.code === 200;
tests["Schema validator GetTerminalInitEventForHarewareIds"] = tv4.validate(data, schema);
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not work". Also, I don't see a question here. And use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37708036/edit) link to edit your question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: @TimPietzcker
Edited my question according to your suggestions, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I still don't see a question or a problem definition.

Comment: ...although the missing closing parenthesis in your regex is a rather obvious problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```regex
^tests\["(.*?)(?::\s*"\s*[^\]]|"\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- require the string to start with `tests["`
- matches the substring inside the first double quotes

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oE9lL6/3

**Sample text**

```
tests["Status code: " +responseCode.code] = responseCode.code === 200;
tests["Schema validator GetTerminalInitEventForHarewareIds"] = tv4.validate(data, schema);
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets the entire match
- Capture group 1 gets just the value inside the first quotes.

  - If the value ends with a `: "` followed by non `]` then the `:` and trailing text is not included
  - If the value ends with a `: "]`  then the `:` and trailing spaces are included

```
MATCH 1
1.  [7-18]  `Status code`

MATCH 2
1.  [78-129]    `Schema validator GetTerminalInitEventForHarewareIds`

MATCH 3
1.  [169-224]   `Schema validator GetTerminalInitEventForHarewareIds: `
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  tests                    'tests'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\]]                    any character except: '\]'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for a very informative answer, I'll definitely use this site in the future: https://regex101.com/